# Response to Gambling and Poker for recreational enjoyment

Tags: games-toys, gambling

What are some of the modern day responses from Gedolim in the Jewish world on individuals who spend time gambling, playing cards etc., outside of a casino?

Comment: Do they gamble actual money? Or just tokens that are returned after?

Comment: @Ariel I am interested in both situations.

Comment: They are very different (I think). Perhaps two separate questions that reference each other?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/gambling-at-casino (your question specifically is not about casino - but I'm not certain that makes any difference).

Comment: http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/develop/01develop.htm

Comment: On individuals, or on their actions? Big difference.

Comment: Are there any tshuvos on this?