# Index cards/flash cards on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Are there any halachic considerations regarding using index cards/flash cards on Shabbat? This may involve going through the pile, quizzing myself, and sorting the cards into different piles.

For reference, here's a similar question regarding playing cards:
[Halachic permissibility of playing cards (i.e., poker) for money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/halachic-permissibility-of-playing-cards-i-e-poker-for-money)