# According to the opinions that playing cards is not stealing, would cheating in the game be considered stealing?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing, gambling

While most halachic authorities consider gambling and card games to be stealing, according to the opinion(s) that permit it, would cheating in the game qualify as stealing? Since cheating is a possibility and perhaps both parties “despair” of that which is put in the middle, could that be a reason why it may not be stealing “after the fact” and not require returning the winnings?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60641/170

Comment: On the contrary, players rely on the assumption that their opponents are not cheating. At the very least, this cheating would presumably be forbidden due to *g'neivas da'as*, if not outright thievery.

Answer (score 2):

Playing cards is never considered as outright "10 commandment"stealing by anybody; it's considered as *similar to stealing* since (according to those opinions who forbid it) nobody has really any intent on losing their money, so since they hope they will win, they very begrudgingly give over their hard-earned bucks to the winner.

Cheating at cards to win money would be outright stealing and forbidden by everybody.